# Does MVC architecture fit javascript widget applications

Tags: javascript, web-services, model-view-controller, backbone.js, widget

We are about to develop IGoogle style news aggregating web application specifically tailored to our needs. I suggested we go MVC way but using javascript and ajax. Also went further to suggest that `Backbone.Js`,`jQuery` and `Underscor.js` are best in organizing javascript apps that are url aware and lighweight. Great seems alright, but now i would like nod from other people who have more experience in this kind of widget development using javascript and applying MVC stack to something that does not provide it native.

For example a widget i am developing as sample does below:

- Supports collapse, expand, Full view
- Displays a chart using Flash
- Columns in the chart can be configured and set using AJAX to webservice

this is perfectly for what Backbone.js can achieve.

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is. Are you asking if Backbone works well with ui widgets?

Comment: Actually, you can wrap non-native components into corresponding ones in any well-designed library. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: @kinakuta Well actually does MVC suit developing UI widgets? and backbone seems to provide  **SOC**,**architecture**

Comment: It seems like a strained application of Backbone. UI widgets work great in conjunction with Backbone views, but Backbone would be providing an unnecessary layer of abstraction for UI widget development.

Comment: @kinakuta So what other choice do i have? ready made toolkits like jQueryUI, Dojo don't seem right for this type of stuff. Enlighten me please

Comment: JQuery makes a good basis for building a UI widget. Plugin development is very simplified and you can find lots of examples of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(we are in the business of writing widgets)

You could write a Widget Class that will have a render function that takes a template and populates it with data while also providing event callbacks ([example](https://github.com/radekstepan/intermine-embedding-examples/blob/master/publications-displayers-imjs/src/presenters/publications/Publications.coffee)). Once this is no longer sufficient, you can extend Backbone which will make working with Collections and Models a breeze ([an overengineered example](https://github.com/radekstepan/intermine-embedding-examples/blob/master/publications-displayers-imjs/src/presenters/publications/Publications.backboned.coffee)).